# PartialView and sections

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that will show a panel and some text like below..

```
<div class="panel panel-warning customHidden" id="infobox">
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> information</div>
<div class="panel-body well-sm">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

I would like the text section of this to be passed on by the view that consumes the partialview. how can i pass the text in and maintain the html div around the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use (ViewBag) in partial view itself. Consider the following snippet

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
}

<div class="panel panel-warning customHidden" id="infobox">
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> information</div>
<div class="panel-body well-sm">
    @ViewBag.Text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewBag element. Is a dynamic object.

```
ViewBag.DivText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem.."
```

Then.. you can use @ViewBag.DivText in your view:

```
<div class="panel panel-warning customHidden" id="infobox">
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> information</div>
<div class="panel-body well-sm">@ViewBag.DivText</div>
```

Comment: Thats one way of doing it thank you, is it possible to do it directly in the views instead of controllers?

Comment: Yes, you can do this in the view:
`@{
ViewBag.DivText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem..";
}`